# Как удалить пустые ноды (без свойств) в Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Как удалить узлы, у которых нет заданных свойств (кроме `<id>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для удаления узлов без определенного св-ва попробуйте

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(n.fooProperty)
DETACH DELETE n
```

для удаления узлов вообще не имеющих свойств:

```
MATCH (n)  
WHERE keys(n) = [] 
DETACH DELETE n
```